# Spark-Bigquery connector in Dataproc notebook

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to use the spark-bigquery connector in a notebook using the spark kernel in a dataproc user-mananaged notebook. I was able to set-up the config properly to use spark-bigquery connector locally, but now that I've switched to the dataproc notebook the code doesn't run anymore (doesn't seem to properly have the connector set-up properly).

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config("spark.jars.packages", "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-3.3-bigquery:0.30.0").config("spark.jars").config('spark.executor.memory', '8g').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([{"a": 1}])
df_subset.write.format("bigquery").option("writeMethod","indirect").mode("overwrite").save(output)
```

Error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o217.save.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: bigquery. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: `.config("spark.jars").` doesnt look right. This setting is supposed to be a "Comma-separated list of jars to include on the driver and executor classpaths."

Comment: I have fixed it to this: `spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").config('spark.jars', 'gs://my-bucket/spark-3.3-bigquery-0.32.2.jar').config('spark.executor.memory', '8g').getOrCreate()`. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

Can point directly to the Dataproc released BQ connector jar from gs://spark-lib/bigquery/. Details here: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example

Can use gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar if you want to always use the latest released Jar.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong kernel in the notebook. I was using the Spark kernel, but once I switched to the Python kernel it worked.